# How do I send all traffic generated by a command through a specific interface? Or, speed test for specific interface?

Tags: vpn, network-speed

I am writing a script that basically scans OpenVPN servers using the openvpn client. By scanning I mean it checks whether if the server is accepting connections or not by attempting a connection, ping time and internet speed.

By default, when you connect to an OpenVPN server all your traffic gets sent to it, unless you change a setting in the config file.
Because the scan is slow and to avoid disturbing the user's browsing and etc..., I can change the setting in the config file and use "ping -I " instead of the regular ping.

However, testing the internet speed is a problem. If I don't change the setting in the config file and all my traffic goes through the VPN, I can successfully use the speedtest-cli command to get the download and upload speeds.

However, speedtest-cli doesn't have any option to specify the interface.

Is there any command that allows me to specify the interface on which to conduct the speed test?

Also, the script is written in python, so I am looking for either a python command or a terminal command to accomplish this.

Also, please note that what I am looking for is download and upload speeds, not NIC speed.

Answer (score 3):

> However, speedtest-cli doesn't have any option to specify the interface.

Yes it does, use the `--source` directive

> --source SOURCE    Source IP address to bind to

```
speedtest-cli --source 10.1.1.3
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that. I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: You should learn to read the documentation, https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli it's not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

With latest cli version you need to use the `-i` flag:

```
speedtest -i 10.1.1.3
```

You can also do this:

```
speedtest -I wlan0
speedtest -I wlan1
speedtest -I eth0
...
```

Currently available flags are (according to the `man`):

```
Speedtest by Ookla is the official command line client for testing the speed and performance of your internet connection.

Version: speedtest 1.2.0.84

Usage: speedtest [<options>]
  -h, --help                        Print usage information
  -V, --version                     Print version number
  -L, --servers                     List nearest servers
  -s, --server-id=#                 Specify a server from the server list using its id
  -I, --interface=ARG               Attempt to bind to the specified interface when connecting to servers
  -i, --ip=ARG                      Attempt to bind to the specified IP address when connecting to servers
  -o, --host=ARG                    Specify a server, from the server list, using its host's fully qualified domain name
  -p, --progress=yes|no             Enable or disable progress bar (Note: only available for 'human-readable'
                                    or 'json' and defaults to yes when interactive)
  -P, --precision=#                 Number of decimals to use (0-8, default=2)
  -f, --format=ARG                  Output format (see below for valid formats)
      --progress-update-interval=#  Progress update interval (100-1000 milliseconds)
  -u, --unit[=ARG]                  Output unit for displaying speeds (Note: this is only applicable
                                    for ‘human-readable’ output format and the default unit is Mbps)
  -a                                Shortcut for [-u auto-decimal-bits]
  -A                                Shortcut for [-u auto-decimal-bytes]
  -b                                Shortcut for [-u auto-binary-bits]
  -B                                Shortcut for [-u auto-binary-bytes]
      --selection-details           Show server selection details
      --ca-certificate=ARG          CA Certificate bundle path
  -v                                Logging verbosity. Specify multiple times for higher verbosity
      --output-header               Show output header for CSV and TSV formats

 Valid output formats: human-readable (default), csv, tsv, json, jsonl, json-pretty

 Machine readable formats (csv, tsv, json, jsonl, json-pretty) use bytes as the unit of measure with max precision

 Valid units for [-u] flag:
   Decimal prefix, bits per second:  bps, kbps, Mbps, Gbps
   Decimal prefix, bytes per second: B/s, kB/s, MB/s, GB/s
   Binary prefix, bits per second:   kibps, Mibps, Gibps
   Binary prefix, bytes per second:  kiB/s, MiB/s, GiB/s
   Auto-scaled prefix: auto-binary-bits, auto-binary-bytes, auto-decimal-bits, auto-decimal-bytes
```